# Issue with parsing json using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

My JSON response in postman looks like this...

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "Details": {
        "seller_id": "165",
        "mobile_no": "9653265987",
        "seller_name": "User A",
        "seller_email_id": "user@gmail.com",
        "company_name": "myCompany",
        "category": "Cosmetics",
        "otp": "1111"
    },
    "message": "Seller Already Registered!!!"
}
```

Now I wanted to give a condition based on whether success is 0 or 1 and so for that I wanted to extract success. Also I want to extract mobile number. But I am not able figure out how to do that.

This is how I am making my Alamofire post request...

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .responseString { (response) in

                if let httpResponse = response.response {
                    print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                        //Do something

                    }
                }
        }
```

I did go through similar issues raised by other users...but couldn't find from them an exact solution for my issue...

Comment: are you using any third party for serialization of data like swiftyjson or gloss..?

Comment: No..just Alamofire..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. Your parameters to `request` don't look quite right.

   - the `parameters` parameter doesn't look right: at best, it's very strange to have a `Parameters` variable (you should use lower case for variables; and this conflicts with an Alamofire type);
   - the encoding should be `URLEncoding.default`. Or, because `URLEncoding.default` *is* the default value, you can omit this altogether.
2. If you want to check for status code, let `validate` do that for you.
3. If you're expecting JSON in response, use `reponseJSON` instead of `responseString`.
4. Use `if let` or `guard let` with `as?` to safely unwrap optionals. Do not use `as!` (unless you are 100% sure that it never could fail ... and when dealing with responses from a remote server, you can never be 100% confident).

Thus:

```
func performRequest(url: String, parameters: [String: String]?, headers: [String: String]?) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any],
                    let success = dictionary["success"] as? Int else {
                        print("success not found")
                        return
                }

                guard success == 1 else {
                    print("web service reported failure")
                    return
                }

                guard let details = dictionary["Details"] as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Did not find details")
                    return
                }

                guard let mobile = details["mobile_no"] as? String else {
                    print("mobile not found")
                    return
                }

                print(mobile)

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed: \(error)")
            }
    }
}
```

---

Or, in your comment below, if you want to `goToSignUpScreen()` if `success` was `0`, then:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
    .validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any],
                let success = dictionary["success"] as? Int else {
                    print("success not found")
                    return
            }

            if success == 0 {
                self.goToSignUpScreen()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed: \(error)")
        }
}
```

Comment: The solution is apt, @Rob. But I had one doubt..it is simple for sure...:)but please consider it as something from a beginner. The doubt is this.. you mentioned this line let success = dictionary["success"] as? Int else {...Now here, if I want to give this...if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                           
                            if result["success"] as! Int == 0 {
                                
                                self.gotToSignUpScreen()
                                
            }
then how'll I mention it in the guard statement?

Comment: First, why go to `response.result.value` rather than using the `value` that `.success(let value)` supplied? Second, why use `as!` instead of `as?`? Only use `!` if you're OK with your app crashing if the cast fails (i.e. you know that it _never_ can happen). But if you want to `goToSignUpScreen` if `success` was zero, you can certainly do that, like shown above.

Comment: how can we send parameter as get method? it will show invalid url

Comment: Yep. It’s very common to do so. But if you’re getting invalid URL, maybe you forget the scheme (the `https://` part, or whatever). I can’t diagnose this on the basis of what you’ve provided here. Post you own question, showing us what you tried and precisely what response/error you got.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { (response) in

                switch response.result{
                case .success(_):
                    print("Success: \(response)")
                    let JsonResponse = response.result.value as? [String: Any]

                    if JsonResponse?["success"] as! Int == 1{
                        let dict = JsonResponse?["Details"] as! [String : Any]
                        let mobileNo = dict["mobile_no"] as! String
                    }
                    else{
                        print("Failed")
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failed: \(error)")
                }
        }
```

Comment: In this line let JsonResponse = response.result.value as? [String: Any] , I'm getting the warning ''cast from String? to unrelated type [String:Any] always fails''.. And it is maybe because of that, in the very next line, it crashes...

Comment: @User.bw don't copy only small part of my code, just replace whole code with your code.

Comment: This solution also worked...but accepted the below answer since it was given in more detail..But thanks...Have given an upvote...:)